# Null pointer exception when copying to a class with a string

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I've seen other post on this forum, that the solution was an unitialized `String`.

Why is this returning a `null pointer exception`, since I'm initializing the string, and the array of `Foo`?

```
class Foo
{
    public String Name = "foobar";
    public int Score = 0;
 };

class Bar
{
    private Foo[] timerScore = new Foo[10];

    //....

    private void xpto()
    {
        timerScore[0].Name = "test"; //<---null pointer exception.why?!
        timerScore[0].Score = 30;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating an array of Foo doesn't create the actual instances of Foo.

You need :

```
private void xpto()
{
    timerScore[0] = new Foo ();
    timerScore[0].Name = "test";
    timerScore[0].Score = 30;
}
```

Comment: that's it....!!! thanks!